# Mono and iOS 6 build error MT0000

Tags: xcode, mono, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, ios6

I have a problem building my app on MonoTouch and iOS 6.

My system configuration is:

- Mac OSX 10.7.4 (Lion)
- MonoTouch 5.2.13
- MonoDevelop 3.0.3.5
- XCode 4.5 with iOS 6 SDK beta 4.

To link new iOS SDK I have selected on MonoDevelop preference SDK location (for me it's on desktop) and i have restarted it.

Now, when I try to build my application, MonoDevelop gives me following error:

> Unexpected error - Please fill a bug report at
>   http://bugzilla.xamarin.com (MT0000)

Can anyone help me to understand what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those versions of Xcode and iOS are under NDA. You need the latest **alpha** ([5.99.x](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/releases/MonoTouch_5/Monotouch_5.99)) release of MonoTouch to be able to try them out.

MonoDevelop will offer it to you if you use the **alpha** channel **and** meet the specific requirements (installing the beta SDK will solve that).

As stated in the [release notes](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/releases/MonoTouch_5/Monotouch_5.99) you'll also need a newer version of MonoDevelop (3.0.4.x) to get everything working properly.