# Unexpected error-Xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, cross-platform, xamarin

Can anybody tell me why am i getting this error during compile time.

> Error MT0000: Unexpected error - Please file a bug report at
>   http://bugzilla.xamarin.com (MT0000)

I'm using Xamarin studio Version 4.2.3 (build 59) and Mono runtime,

Mono 3.2.6 ((no/9b58377) 
GTK+ 2.24.23 
theme: Raleigh GTK# (2.12.0.0)
Package version: 302060000

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 5.0 (3332.25)
Build 5A1413

I have made a hard Google but i could not resolve my problem. I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193146/mono-and-ios-6-build-error-mt0000) thread. Cleaning the project did not help me.

Please help me out.

Comment: Can you try isolating issue (build project by project, then class by class etc)? So as a result you will have either small solution which you can share with us / xamarin support, or you'll find 'bad' code or configuration which you could rewrite.

Comment: @Lanorkin: i have only one project with three classes in my solution, how to build it separately(class by class)..?

Comment: Exclude two classes, leave one. Build. Success? Add class. Failed? try commenting out parts of classes. Or is is that your current environment doesn't work at all, on any sources?

Comment: it worked only when i have removed all the classes and added new one. and in the process of add/remove my designer class got duplicated.       thanks for ur response

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the Linker settings to "Do not Link"?